# Natural Transformation: Direct Products

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

I have result that tells me $$\displaystyle \varphi : \text{Hom}_R \bigg(A, \prod_{i \in I} B_i \bigg) \to \prod_{i \in I} \text{Hom}_R(A, B_i)$$ is a $Z(R)$-isomorphism. The next result tells me that it is natural (which is the part I'm not understanding):

> The isomorphism $\varphi$ is natural: if $(C_j)_{j \in J}$ is a family of left $R$-modules and, for each $i \in I$, there exist $j \in J$ and an $R$-map $\sigma_{ij} : B_i \to C_j$, then there is a commutative diagram
>   $\require{AMScd}$
>   \begin{CD}
>     \text{Hom}_R \bigg(A, \prod_{i \in I} B_i\bigg) @>\varphi>> \prod_{i \in I} \text{Hom}_R(A, B_i)\\
>     @V \sigma_* V V@VV \widetilde \sigma V\\
>     \text{Hom}_R \bigg( A, \prod_{j \in J} C_j \bigg) @>>\varphi> \prod_{j \in J} \text{Hom}_R(A, C_j)
>     \end{CD}
>   where $\displaystyle \sigma : \prod_{i \in I} B_i \to \prod_{j \in J} C_j$ is given by $(b_i) \mapsto (\sigma_{ij}b_i)$, and $\sigma_*$ is the induced map, and $\widetilde \sigma : (g_i) \mapsto (\sigma_{ij}g_i)$.

My definition for natural transformation is:

> Let $S, T : \mathcal A \to \mathcal B$ be covariant functors. A natural transformation $\tau : S \to T$ is a one-parameter family of morphisms in $\mathcal B$, $\tau = (\tau_A : SA \to TA)_{A \in \text{Obj(A)}}$ making the following diagram commute for all $f : A \to A'$ in $\mathcal A$:
>   $\require{AMScd}$
>   \begin{CD}
>     SA @>\tau_A>> TA\\
>     @V S_f V V @VV T_f V\\
>     SA' @>>\tau_{A'}> TA'
>     \end{CD}

I'm having trouble figuring out what are $S, T$? Or even $\mathcal A, \mathcal B$?

For instance, am I looking at $\mathcal A$ is a category where the objects are families of left $R$-modules $(B_i)_{i \in I}$? and then $S$ is a functor which takes this category to the category of sets, defined by $$S\big( (B_i)_{i \in I}\big) = \text{Hom}_R\bigg(A, \prod_{i \in I} B_i \bigg)?$$

Or is $\mathcal A$ the category of left $R$-modules where we just look as products as a special case? My concern with this is that maps between products like $\sigma : \prod B_i \to \prod C_j$ are defined in a special way, so where is this taken into account?

To conclude this post, I'm hoping someone can help me see the result in terms of the definition I've been given for natural transformations. (As for showing that the diagram was commutative, that was fairly straight forward.)

**Source**: "Introduction to Homological Algebra", Joseph Rotman, Page 54, Theorem 2.30.

Comment: Could you provide the reference where this results are stated?

Comment: @GiorgioMossa, updated post with that information!

Comment: How much category theory do you know?

Comment: @Chilango, the basics. Chapter 1 of the book I referenced.

Comment: @BarbaricVulture: I only know this in a categorical setting.The result you are referring to expresses the fact that the hom functor preserves the product, which is a kind of limit in the category $R-Mod$.  See answer number 1 [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742631/preservation-of-limit-by-hom-naturality-question) .

Comment: @Chilango, I think the first line in my post says that "hom preserves product" (the result I reference). It's the naturality of it that I'm not understanding. The author says it's a natural isomorphism, and I'm not seeing the details of what that really means with the definition of natural transformation he gave us earlier. I've worked with limits before, but the author hasn't introduced that yet, and I'd like to understand it the way it was intended.

Comment: @BarbaricVulture: I do not see how you can separate naturality from limits.The RHS is a limit of sets which happens to be a set of choice functions. To each of these there is a unique corresponding $f:A\rightarrow \prod $ on the LHS. The uniqueness requires the UMP of the limit and the naturality requires knowledge of what $hom$ and $\prod $ do to arrows. I am no expert however so maybe there is another way of seeing this.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I believe that the book try to do the following thing (although avoiding a lot of details).

As a general case for every category $\mathbf C$ you can build a category $\text{Fam}(\mathbf C)$ whose:

- **objects** are families of objects in $\mathbf C$, that is stuff like $(c_i)_{i \in I}$ where each $c_i$ is in $\mathbf C$
- **morphisms** from $(c_i)_{i \in I}$ to $(d_j)_{j \in J}$ are pairs $\langle f, \sigma \rangle$ where $f \colon J \to I$ and
  $\sigma=\langle\sigma_j \colon c_{f(j)} \to d_j\rangle_{j \in J}$
- composition of pair of morphisms
  $$(c_i)_{i \in I} \stackrel{\langle f, \sigma\rangle}{\longrightarrow}(d_j)_{j \in J} \stackrel{\langle g,\tau                         
  \rangle}{\longrightarrow}(e_l)_{l \in L}$$
  is defined to be the morphism
  $$(c_i)_{i \in I} \stackrel{\langle h, \psi\rangle}{\longrightarrow} (e_l)_{l \in L}$$
  where $h=f \circ g$ and $\psi_{l}=\tau_l \circ \sigma_{g(l)}\colon c_{f(g(l))} \to e_l$ for every $l \in L$.
  The identities are the obvious ones.

If $\mathbf C$ is a category with products we have a functor
$$\prod \colon \text{Fam}(\mathbf C) \to \mathbf C$$
that associates to every family $(c_i)_{i \in I}$ (a choice of) its product $\prod_I c_i$.

The arrow part of this functor is not as such straightforward to describe but you can try as an exercise to write it out.

Now back to your problem. As a start we know that for every ring $R$ the category $\mathbf{Mod}_R$ of $R$ modules and $R$-linear maps
has products hence for the observation above you have a functor
$$\prod \colon \mathbf{Fam}(\mathbf {Mod}_R) \to \mathbf{Mod}_R$$

On the other hand for every $R$-module $A$ you also have a functor
$$y_A \colon \textbf{Mod}_R \to \textbf{Mod}_{Z(R)}$$
that sends every module $B$ into the $Z(R)$-module $\text{Hom}_R(A,B)$.
This functor extend naturally to a functor
$$\bar y_A \colon \textbf{Fam}(\textbf{Mod}_R) \to \textbf{Fam}(\textbf{Mod}_{Z(R)})$$
that sends every family $(B_i)_{i \in I}$ of $R$-modules into the family of $Z(R)$-module
$(\text{Hom}_{Z(R)}(A,B_i))_{i \in I}$.
Also the category $\textbf{Mod}_{Z(R)}$ admits its own product functor $\prod$.

From these data you obtain the following functors

$$\mathbf{Fam}(\mathbf{Mod}_R) \stackrel{\prod}{\longrightarrow} \textbf{Mod}_R \stackrel{y_A}{\longrightarrow} \textbf{Mod}_{Z(R)}$$
and
$$\mathbf{Fam}(\mathbf{Mod}_R) \stackrel{\bar y_A}{\longrightarrow} \textbf{Fam}(\textbf{Mod}_{Z(R)})                                  
\stackrel{\prod}{\longrightarrow} \textbf{Mod}_{Z(R)}$$

The first functor associates to each family $(B_i)_{i \in I}$ of $R$-modules the $Z(R)$-module $\text{Hom}_R(A,\prod B_i)$
the second one the module $\prod \text{Hom}_R(A,B_i)$.

The statement of the theorem is saying the family of morphisms $\varphi$ is a natural transformation for these two functors.

Comment: The existance of the mappings $\sigma_{i,j}$ in the theorem statements can be easily rephrased in the existance of a morphism $\langle f,\sigma\rangle$ in the category $\mathbf{Fam}(\mathbf{Mod}_R)$.

Comment: By the way I believe that there is a typo in the book, the mappings $\sigma_*$ and $\tilde \sigma$ are not well defined: in order to let $(\sigma_{ij} b_i)$ being an element of $\prod_j C_j$ one have to specify **for every $j \in J$ an** $i \in I$ such that $\sigma_{ij} \colon B_i \to C_j$ is an $R$-module morphims, instead of requiring that **for every $i \in I$ there is a $j \in J$...**

Comment: Thanks! This answer is great. I had not heard of $\text{Fam}(C)$ before. The first time I worked through Rotman I skipped through the details of this problem, and now going back, I realized there were a lot of important details I missed. Once I work through the details of the last paragraph you wrote, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Happy to have been helpful. The hardest part would be to provide the description of the arrow part of the functor $\prod$, you can skip at first, there is an easy way to characterize this functor by looking to a different presentation of the category $\mathbf{Fam}(\mathbf C)$ which make use of comma and functor categories so maybe it's a little too soon for them.

Comment: @GiorgioMossa, How would one describe this $\operatorname{Fam}(C)$ in terms of functor categories? If the index set $I$ (viewed as a discrete category) is fixed then all we're really interested in is the functor category $C^I,$ but here I am struggling to see if there's a natural way to formalize the idea that  $\operatorname{Fam}(C)$ is the same as "$C^I$ where $I$ is allowed to vary amongst all sets" somehow.

Comment: @A.P. functor categories aren't needed to describe $\mathbf{Fam}(\mathbf {C})$, instead you can use comma-categories to describe $\mathbf{Fam}(\mathbf C)$. Functor categories are needed to deal with products (i.e. limits) to easily describe the image of a morphism through $\prod$ using the universal property of products, this is needed because cones are object in a functor category.

Comment: @GiorgioMossa Would you mind describing how one can use comma categories to describe $\operatorname{Fam}(C)$?

Comment: @A.P. now that I'm thinking better I realize I should have said 2-comma category: the category $\text{Fam}(\mathbf C)$ is the comma category $(i \downarrow \hat{\mathbf C})$ where $\hat {\mathbf C}$ is the constant functor (from the terminal category in $\mathbf C$) that select the object $\mathbf C$ in $\mathbf {Cat}$ and $i \colon \mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf {Cat}$ is obvious embedding. The objects are functors from sets in $\mathbf C$, the morphisms a 2-commutative triangles in $\mathbf{Cat}$.

Comment: @GiorgioMossa Nice, thank you! I forgot that picking an object in $C$ is the same as picking a functor from $1$ to $C,$ and with this missing piece the puzzle is complete :-)